# Unable to Locate process running on http://localhost

Tags: linux, java, tomcat

A process is running on my machine on  http://localhost as URL, without the port number.

I tried to Kill all process of NodeJs and tomcat.

Still the program is running when i hit

http://localhost.

Any guesses what is actually happening? or workaround on killing this process.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo netstat -nlp
```

This will give you the PID and program name that listens to that port. Example output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1472/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1520/cupsd
```

You will see something running either on port 443 or on port 80.